# how to club the data split by split function

Tags: javascript, date

my data is dat1;
the split statement is

```
var splitstr =  dat1.split("-");
```

I have splited the data from this format

```
2010 -02-02 to Element 0 = 2010
Element 1 = 05
Element 2 = 22
```

this format..Using  split function,

i want to arrange that like 2010,02,02 how can i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply replace `-` with `,`:

```
dat1.replace('-', ',');
```

That will give you: `2010,02,02`

Comment: This will only replace the first instance of '-' in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can either alter the original string

```
var date = "2010-02-02";
var formatted_date = date.replace(/-/g, ',');
```

Note that the `g` flag must be used to replace all instances of '-'.

Or, you can create a new string from the array that you've created from your original `split`

```
var split_date = date.split('-');
...
var formatted_date = split_date.join(',');
```